# Vue Owl Carousel crash when resizing the window

Tags: vue.js

I use Vue-Own-Carousel in my web page.

it's working fine when the width of my windows is under 999px. If not, the carousel crash. 
Any idea how to fix that ? 
I tried to config responsive carousel but still not working.

```
  <carousel 
   :responsive="{0:{items:1,nav:false},600:{items:3,nav:false},900: 
   {items:3,nav:false},1000:{items:3,nav:false}}">
  </carousel>
```

Thank you in advance.

Here is the official doc..

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-owl-carousel